# How can I find $P(X>0 | Y<0)$?

Tags: probability

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are standard normal random variable with $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. How can I find the conditional probability $P(X>0 | Y<0)$?

I know that 
$$  P(X>0 | Y<0) = 2 P(X>0\:\text{  and }\:Y<0)$$
So, how can I compute the above probability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The covariance shows that $X=\frac1{\sqrt2}(Y-Z)$ where $(Y,Z)$ is i.i.d. standard normal. Thus, the value $P(Y\lt0)=\frac12$ implies that
$$
P(X\gt0\mid Y\lt0)=2P(X\gt0\gt Y)=2P(Z\lt Y\lt0).
$$
By symmetry, $P(Z\lt Y\lt0)=P(Y\lt Z\lt0)$ hence
$$
P(X\gt0\mid Y\lt0)=P(Z\lt Y\lt0)+P(Y\lt Z\lt0)=P(Y\lt0,Z\lt0).
$$
Finally, by independence of $Y$ and $Z$,
$$
P(X\gt0\mid Y\lt0)=P(Y\lt0)P(Z\lt0)=\frac14.
$$

Answer (score 2):

For a $n\times 1$ random Gaussian vector $X$, the density function is $$f_{X}(x)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}\det(C)}\exp\left(-(x-\mu)^TC^{-1}(x-\mu)\right)$$ where $\mu$ is its mean vector and $C$ is the covariance matrix. So, for your case the joint density of $X,Y$ is $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi\det C}\exp\left(-[X\quad Y]C^{-1}[X \quad Y]^T\right)$$ where $$C=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1/2\\
1/2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$ Hope you can now do it yourself.